# Swift: Unable to input name from keyboard auto-fill / clipboard for alphabet only

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textfield that has contentType name. I have added some validations to restrict users from entering non alphabet characters, but doing so, it threw me out using the keyboard autofill feature.

Here is my code...

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  if range.location == 0 && string == " " { // prevent space on first character
     return false
  }
  if textField.text?.last == " " && string == " " { // allowed only single space
     return false
  }
  
  if string == " " { return true } // now allowing space between name
  
  if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letters.inverted) != nil {
     return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Please note that, it's working totally fine if a user types manually. It's not working for these 2 edge cases-

**1- Copy Paste a Name that has a whitespace between them**

**2- Keyboard autofill name**

Comment: Can you post few autofill/copy pasted inputs that don't work?

Comment: "First Last" excluding double quotes. (basically full names containing whitespaces) @SamB

Answer (score 0):

When a user is typing a string, this method get invoked for each character user type. The current validation rules you have are fine for this scenario. However during copy-paste/auto fill, the method gets called with the entire string. So if you copy paste *First Last*, then `string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letters.inverted)` is actually `not nil`, since there is a space in the `string`(*First Last*). So you can check the length of the `string` and if it is larger than 1 add different set of rules.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.count == 1 {
        if range.location == 0 && string == " " { // prevent space on first character
           return false
        }
        if textField.text?.last == " " && string == " " { // allowed only single space
           return false
        }
        
        if string == " " { return true } // now allowing space between name
        
        if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letters.inverted) != nil {
           return false
        }
        return true
        
    } else {
        //do validations for copyPasted/auto-fill inputs here, when there are more than one character
        return true
    }
}
```